# What is the best approach to manage multi page JavaScript in Rails application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, frameworks

I am building a Rails application which contains hundreds of html pages and it requires unique javascript on each page including js libraries. Rails because I am more familiar with it and also for other backend purposes.

To get an idea you can take an example of simple code conversion (eg. XML to JSON) online tools. Here the code for converting xml data to json is written in javascript on the HTML page. In my case, I want to make 100's of such tools (ie. csv to json, html to pdf etc), where each one is independent of other. I m not storing any data from these in the database but only the user info who is going to use tools. So basically all pages will be rendered from a single controller.

Please suggest me better approach for that or should I continue writing javascript on every single HTML page. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure to have understoo your app structure. When you say "pages" is it controller views ?

Comment: I've edited the question please check.

Comment: Technically rails will only be used for storing user data and those "pages" will be rendered by single controller only. They have nothing to do with database

Comment: HTML to PDF is not an easy to do on the client properly with javascript. What you want to achieve sounds a bit optimistic. Application have structures and multiple controllers & models in order to avoid such heavy client pages. Why not balancing between server and client more equally ? Moreover what you describe does not seem to fit into Rails classic MVC structure

Comment: Yeah, I know its bit odd. For heavy tasks, I'll be using third party API's to balance the load on the server side. But for simple formatting and text conversions, I want to stick with javascript to lessen the burden on the server. Coming to rails, that part will be used for users who sign up on site and choose more features, only that part will be handled in Rails. Otherwise, it continues to run as a collection of several "use and throw" tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case above I would like to suggest using coffeescript OOP method, below is the detail and some code for your requirement

- I suggest you to use coffee with class method and then check each page with event turbolinks:load
- you can check which page with name of 
  controller and the the method for example $(".purchase_requests.new")[0] meaning the controller is purchase_requests and the method new
- also I suggest you to read brandon hilkert blog for some additional reference below is [the link](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/organizing-javascript-in-rails-application-with-turbolinks/)

sample coffeescript with check each page load

```
class App.PurchaseRequest

  renderYourJavascript: ->
    console.log "purchase request js"

$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  if $(".purchase_requests.new")[0] || $(".purchase_requests.edit")[0]  
    purchase_request = new App.PurchaseRequest
    purchase_request.renderYourJavascript()
```

Answer (score 0):

I not surely I understand your ideal. But, I think you can try to save your javascript code  into database.
And you use a controller for read javascript code from database and render it as javascript file.

Example:

```
# routes.rb
get '/js/:file_name.js', to: 'javascripts#show'

# model
Javascript( id: :interget, name: :string, content: :text )

# controller
class JavascriptsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      js = Javascript.find_by_name(params[:file_name])
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js { js.content if js.present? }
      end       
   end
end
```

I try to simply describe my ideal. Please checking again and surely it works as you want.

Hope its help.

Comment: Thanks, for the response The single page here is itself a whole single page application and require much javascript code and dependent libraries. I don't think storing them in the database is a good approach.  Actually, I don't even want to use the database for that. I have edited the question with  details. Please check ...